# 2-descent on elliptic curves, and units modulo squares of units

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, rational-points, descent

**Setup**: Let $p$ be a prime, let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}_p[x]$ be a separable monic cubic polynomial cutting out the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_{K_f}$ in the etale algebra $K_f := \mathbb{Q}_p[x]/(f(x))$, and let $E$ denote the elliptic curve with affine equation $y^2 = f(x)$. The standard theory of $2$-descent on $E$ gives us an injective group homomorphism

$$E(\mathbb{Q}_p)/2E(\mathbb{Q}_p) \hookrightarrow H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p,E[2]) \simeq \{\delta \in K_f^\times/K_f^{\times2} : \operatorname{Nm}(\delta) \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}\}.$$

In fact, because $f$ cuts out the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_{K_f}$, the image of the above map lies in the unit subgroup $\{\delta \in \mathcal{O}_{K_f}^\times/\mathcal{O}_{K_f}^{\times 2} : \operatorname{Nm}(\delta) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times 2}\}$, with equality when $p$ is odd.

Next, let $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}_p[x]$ be a separable monic quartic polynomial such that the genus-$1$ curve $C$ with affine equation $y^2 = g(x)$ is a $2$-covering of $E$, and let $J$ denote the Jacobian of $C$. Once again, we have an injective group homomorphism

$$J(\mathbb{Q}_p)/2J(\mathbb{Q}_p) \hookrightarrow H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p,J[2]).$$

Let $K_g := \mathbb{Q}_p[x]/(g(x))$, and let $\mathcal{O}_{K_g}$ denote its ring of integers. Unlike in the cubic case, we cannot necessarily identify $H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p, J[2])$ with units in $K_g$ modulo squares of units. Indeed, consider the short exact sequence
$$1 \to J[2] \to \operatorname{Res}_{K_g/\mathbb{Q}_p}\mu_2/\mu_2 \to \mu_2 \to 1$$
that realizes $J[2]$ as the kernel of the norm map on $\operatorname{Res}_{K_g/\mathbb{Q}_p}\mu_2/\mu_2$. Taking Galois cohomology, we obtain a group homomorphism
$$H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p, J[2]) \to S := \ker\big(\operatorname{Nm}\colon H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p, \operatorname{Res}_{K_g/\mathbb{Q}_p} \mu_2/\mu_2) \to H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p,\mu_2)\big)$$
The group $\{\delta \in K_g^\times/K_g^{\times2}\mathbb{Q}_p^\times : \operatorname{Nm}(\delta) \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}\}$ is a subgroup of $S$, and the image of $J(\mathbb{Q}_p)/2J(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ in $S$ lies in this subgroup. In fact, because $f$ cuts out the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_{K_f}$, it follows that $g$ cuts out the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_{K_g}$, and so the image of $J(\mathbb{Q}_p)/2J(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ lies in the unit subgroup $\{\delta \in \mathcal{O}_{K_g}^\times/\mathcal{O}_{K_g}^{\times2}\mathbb{Z}_p^\times : \operatorname{Nm}(\delta) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times 2}\}$.

Combining the above data, we see that at least when $p$ is odd, we have a composite group homomorphism
$$(\star)\quad\{\delta \in \mathcal{O}_{K_f}^\times/\mathcal{O}_{K_f}^{\times2} : \operatorname{Nm}(\delta) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times 2}\} \simeq E(\mathbb{Q}_p)/2E(\mathbb{Q}_p) = J(\mathbb{Q}_p)/2J(\mathbb{Q}_p) \to \{\delta \in \mathcal{O}_{K_g}^\times/\mathcal{O}_{K_g}^{\times 2}\mathbb{Z}_p^\times : \operatorname{Nm}(\delta) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times 2}\}.$$
**Question**: Does the map $(\star)$ from units modulo squares of $K_f$ to units modulo squares of $K_g$ have a natural interpretation in terms of the cubic and quartic algebras $K_f$ and $K_g$? I.e., can this map be constructed without relying on the connection to elliptic curves as a crutch?

**Partial answer**: I guess the answer is obvious when $g$ has a linear factor over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, for then $K_f$ is a sub-algebra of $K_g$, and the inclusion $K_f \hookrightarrow K_g$ induces the map $(\star)$. But what if $g$ has only quadratic or quartic irreducible factors?

Comment: You need to assume that p is a prime of good reduction for your model, i. e. It does not divide the discriminant. Otherwise your integrality statements won't always hold.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thanks for this correction! I'm using Section 6.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1007.pdf, where it is argued that (at least in the cubic case), the integrality statement holds under the weaker assumption that $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x)) = \mathcal{O}_{K_f}$ is the maximal order. Anyway, it would be very nice to understand the map $(\star)$ in the good reduction case!

Comment: Isn't there some ambiguity in the choice of isomorphism $E\simeq J$?

Comment: @Jef That's a great point! My understanding is that one could replace all instances of $J$ with $E$ and the question will make sense. Once isomorphisms $E[2] \simeq \ker(\operatorname{Res}_{K_f/\mathbb{Q}_p} \mu_2 \to \mu_2)$ and $J[2] \simeq \ker ((\operatorname{Res}_{K_g/\mathbb{Q}_p} \mu_2)/\mu_2 \to \mu_2)$ are chosen, I think there are no ambiguities?

Comment: That seems correct. Anyway, I think this is a very interesting question, and I hope you find an answer :) I would be curious to see it!